# Python 3.8 installation problem on MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, homebrew, python-3.8

Assalamualaikum, My operating system is macOS Catalina. I installed python3.8 through homebrew but When I checked the python version, using the command `python3 --version`, it is showing Python 3.7.3.

Even if I try to install python@3.7 version , it is showing the same Python 3.7.3 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew installed `python3` in `/usr/local/bin`. Either that directory is not in your `PATH` variable, or it appears after `/usr/bin`, so that `/usr/bin/python3` is found first during command lookup. Make sure you have something like

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

in your `.zprofile`.

Comment: Jazak Allah Khair . Thanks a lot. Yeah after adding   export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" in my .zshrc file , it works.

Comment: I would add it to `.zprofile` instead. `.zshrc` is sourced by *every* interactive shell you start, which in theory means you could end up with the directory prepended to `PATH` multiple times if you had deeply nested shells. (Something that would happen only rarely, I know.) Since `PATH` is exported, prepending to it once in your initial login shell is sufficient.